# Determining the critical points of a two-variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

**Edit**

So it seems that, if we assume the function is correct, then the suggested solution is most likely wrong. However, I am inclined to think that the question has been tweaked while the answer remained as it is. Thus, as a challenge to myself, I am trying to figure out the original function, assuming the suggested solution is correct. Just putting this out there too since I’ve already made the post; if anyone wants to try (and succeeds), feel free to pen down what the function could be (either in an answer or a comment) :)

**Question**

Find all the critical points of $f$, where $$f(x, y) = \frac 1 2 x^2 - x + ay(x - 1) - \frac 1 3 y^3 - a^2y^2$$ and $a$ is a constant.

**My working**

I know that, for a two-variable function, a critical point is one where the partial derivates with respect to both variables is zero. In our case, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac {\partial{f}} {\partial{x}} & = x - 1 + ay\\[2 mm]
& = 0
\end{aligned}$$ and
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac {\partial{f}} {\partial{y}} & = a(x - 1) - y^2 - 2a^2y\\[2 mm]
& = 0.
\end{aligned}$$
Now, substituting the first equation into the second gives $$a(-ay) - y^2 -2a^2y = 0$$ which implies that $$y = 0$$ or $$y = -3a^2.$$ Finally, we see that the critical points are $(1, 0)$ and $(1 + 3a^2, -3a^2)$.

**Answer**

The answer, however, is $(0, 0)$ and $(1 - a^3, a^2)$.

---

Is the suggested answer incorrect? If not, then where have I gone wrong? Any intuitive explanations or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Almost correct. The second critical point is $(1 + 3a^{\color{red}{3}},\ -3a^2)$.

Observe that $(0, 0)$ cannot be a critical point, for in the $x$ derivative you would get $-1 = 0$. There must be an error in the book/notes.

Comment: @EnricoM. yes, that's what I thought. I was almost starting to believe that my elementary calculus and algebra skills were failing me...

Comment: Haha no, you did pretty well indeed. Sometimes books or notes carries error in their solutions. Trust yourself! :)

Comment: @EnricoM. as a bonus, I’m trying to find what the function could possibly have been such that the critical points given by the answer are satisfied. (I feel like the question has been edited, but the answers were not changed accordingly). However, I’m not making any progress. Haha! Feel free to try it out if you have time and let me know if you find anything :)